# Iterating over dictionary in ansible

Tags: python, ansible, openshift, prometheus

I am using ansible get data from prometheus in OpenShift environment. I am creating a dictionary like the following output. Now I need to iterate over this dictionary to calculate the CPU usage percentage (I know there are prometheus metrics for that) like cpu_used*100/cpu_total.

I tried using `with_items:`  but `item."anything"` fails!

```
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "msg": {
        "machine-infra01": {
            "cpu_total": 8,
            "cpu_used": 0.23
        },
        "machine-infra02": {
            "cpu_total": 12,
            "cpu_used": 0.3
        },
        "machine-infra03": {
            "cpu_total": 12,
            "cpu_used": 0.44
        },
        "machine-master01": {
            "cpu_total": 8,
            "cpu_used": 0.21
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you may need to use `with_dict` or the new loop constructs, depending on Ansible version.
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-dict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this, which iterates over the your dictionary of dictionaries, builds a new dictionary containing the `cpu_percent` values, and then recursively merges that with the original value:

```
  vars:
    data: "{{ lookup('file', 'foo.json') | from_json }}"
    percents: {}

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        percents: "{{ percents | combine({ item.key : { 'cpu_percent': item.value.cpu_used*100/item.value.cpu_total }}) }}"
      with_dict: "{{ data }}"
    - set_fact:
        data: "{{ data | combine(percents, recursive=True) }}"
    - debug:
        var: data
```

Output:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "data": {
        "machine-infra01": {
            "cpu_percent": 2.875, 
            "cpu_total": 8, 
            "cpu_used": 0.23
        }, 
        "machine-infra02": {
            "cpu_percent": 2.5, 
            "cpu_total": 12, 
            "cpu_used": 0.3
        }, 
        "machine-infra03": {
            "cpu_percent": 3.6666666666666665, 
            "cpu_total": 12, 
            "cpu_used": 0.44
        }, 
        "machine-master01": {
            "cpu_percent": 2.625, 
            "cpu_total": 8, 
            "cpu_used": 0.21
        }
    }
}
```